# Why should I use Reify instead of proxy in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Why should I use Reify instead of proxy in clojure?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The method bodies of `reify` are lexical closures, and can refer to the surrounding local scope. `reify` differs from `proxy` in that:

- Only protocols or interfaces are supported, no concrete superclass.
- The method bodies are true methods of the resulting class, not external fns.
- Invocation of methods on the instance is direct, not using map lookup.
- No support for dynamic swapping of methods in the method map.

The result is better performance than proxy, both in construction and invocation. `reify` is preferable to `proxy` in all cases where its constraints are not prohibitive.

Source: http://clojure.org/datatypes

Answer (score 13):

Use `reify` where you would once use `proxy`, unless you need to override base class methods.