# Clojure Proxy Java Templates

Tags: clojure

### Context

I have this piece of Java Code

```
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    });
```

I want to convert it into Clojure.

### What I know

```
(. btn setOnAction (proxy .... ????? .... ))
```

### Question:

How do I handle EventHandler part in Clojure? I believe this is a Java Template. How do I create templated objects in Clojure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java they're called [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), not Templates. Furthermore, they're implemented using type erasure, i.e. there's no generic information [in the compiled bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure), so that `EventHandler<Foobar>` objects are compiled to be non-generified `EventHandler` instances.

That said, Clojure doesn't even try to support them. Your Java code translates into

```
(.setOnAction btn 
  (proxy [EventHandler] []
    (handle [event]
      (println "Hello World"))))
```

See the documentation on [`proxy`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/proxy) and on [Java interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop) for more details on the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to reify. An example:

```
(import [javax.swing JFrame JButton])
(import [java.awt.event  ActionListener])

(def f (JFrame. "Test"))
(def b (JButton. "OK"))

(.add (.getContentPane f) b)
(.addActionListener b
   (reify ActionListener
      (actionPerformed [this event]
         (println "Event is " event))
 ))
(.show f)
```

See this thread for proxy vs. reify
[Why should I use Reify instead of proxy in clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821892/why-should-i-use-reify-instead-of-proxy-in-clojure)

Comment: This is helfpul; I've been using proxy all these days, unaware of the performance hits.