# Unit test for this function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

have a function to get the data from Firestore in CLojure, and I have no idea to whrite unit test for it.
Can you please help?

```
(defn get-user-collection-ref
  [db user-id]
  (-> db
      (.collection "credits")
      (.document user-id)
      (.collection "transactions")))
```

Comment: What do you want to test, first of all? that your real database returns the collection ref? then you need integration test, not the unit test (meaning that you would need some db deployed for test reasons). Or you just need to check that upon calling this function your db object gets the needed methods called with expected params? then you need to lookup filestore's docs for some database mocking features, i guess.

Comment: As leetwinski pointed out, an integration test is probably more suited here. You won't get much far with a pure unit test. And implementing mock implementation just for the sake of unit test doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reify` or `proxy` to create anonymous instances of classes and interfaces. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821892/why-should-i-use-reify-instead-of-proxy-in-clojure) for which to use. I'm afraid I don't really know much about Firestore, but you should be able to write a mock implementation fairly easily if that's what you're trying to achieve.