# Clojure equivalent of reagent cursor to update nested map and access new value

Tags: syntax, clojure

I find myself doing a lot of
`(get-in (swap! nested-map update-in [:a :b] update-fn) [:a :b])` to update a new value and then access it atomically. It seems a bit clunky to me - is there a more elegant way of doing this? `reagent` has the `cursor` idea which works nicely as once you define the cursor the above just becomes `(swap! cursor update-fn)`.

I found https://github.com/rlewczuk/clj-cursor which seems to be what I want but maybe overkill?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing your own cursor based on the [`clojure.lang.IAtom`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IAtom.java) interface is fairly straight-forward:

```
(defn my-cursor [target-atom path]
  (reify clojure.lang.IAtom
    (swap [_this f] (get-in (swap! target-atom update-in path f) path))))
```

Note that `clojure.lang.IAtom` may be considered an *implementation detail* of Clojure so whether you want to depend on it is up to you.

Here is an example:

```
(def nested-map (atom {}))
(defn update-fn [x] (inc (or x 0)))

(def c (my-cursor nested-map [:a :b]))

(swap! c update-fn)
;; => 1

(deref nested-map)
;; => {:a {:b 1}}
```

Implementing [`IDeref`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IDeref.java) may also be useful:

```
(defn my-cursor [target-atom path]
  (reify clojure.lang.IAtom
    (swap [_this f] (get-in (swap! target-atom update-in path f) path))
    clojure.lang.IDeref
    (deref [_this] (get-in (deref target-atom) path))))
```

Even if you don't have to implement the other methods of the interfaces, it is *nevertheless a good idea*.

A previous version of this answer used `proxy` but `reify` is [probably better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821892/why-should-i-use-reify-instead-of-proxy-in-clojure).

Comment: I like this a lot, thank you. When you say implementation detail, you mean an update to the language could break this right? Should be safe with Clojure :)

Comment: @alex314159 Yes, exactly, but I don't think it is very likely. I would not worry too much :-)

Comment: I am curious - why does `(swap [f]...)` get called through `swap!` not `swap`?

Comment: Take a look at the implementation at `defn swap!`: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2362 The Clojure source code is very readable (and hackable ;-) )

Comment: @alex314159 You're welcome! I just edited my answer slightly to use `reify` instead of `proxy`. See the link at the bottom of my answer why that is.

Comment: This approach is good, but you really should implement the other methods. Otherwise `(swap! (my-cursor p a) * 2)` will throe an exception, for example.

Comment: @amalloy I agree but in this context I think the brevity of the answer is more important.

Answer (score 3):

If you are specifically writing `(get-in (swap! m update-in ks f) ks)` a lot, you can obviously just define that as a function yourself:

```
(defn swap-at-path! [m ks f & args]
  (-> (apply swap! m update-in ks f args)
      (get-in ks)))
```

You only need a library like cursor to do more complicated things than that.